# How do i divide two self created columns in a SQL query select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having some difficulty with a very simple test query that I just cannot get to work. Here is the current query:

```
SELECT 
    REQUESTID AS "Request ID",
    10 AS "Num1",
    5 AS "Num2",
    'Num1' / 'Num2' AS "N1_DividedBy_N2_Result"
FROM 
    RM.CUSTINCDT;
```

and it I get this error when I run it:

> ORA-01722: invalid number
> 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
> *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
> *Action:   Specify a valid number.

It should be outputting this, but all I get is the error above:

| Request ID | Num1 | Num2 | N1_DividedBy_N2_Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14111487 | 10 | 5 | 2 |
| 14116522 | 10 | 5 | 2 |
| 14116477 | 10 | 5 | 2 |
| 14116425 | 10 | 5 | 2 |

I am using Oracle Developer 21.4.3

Comment: `'Num1'` is a character string literal, not a column reference - and you can't divide a string by another string. But that doesn't really matter, you can't reference a column created in the same SELECT list.

Comment: What about if they are wrapped in a common table expression first? Would that work?

Comment: Yes, or a _derived table_ - what Oracle calls in-line view. But use double quotes for columns names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like

```
SELECT "Request ID", "NUM1"/"NUM2" AS RESULT
FROM (
    SELECT 
        REQUESTID AS "Request ID",
        10 AS "NUM1",
        5 AS "NUM2"
    FROM RM.CUSTINCDT
)
```

Comment: Doesn't Oracle require a name for the derived table?

Comment: @jarlh No, it does not require an alias. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8gJUGY1v)

Comment: @jarlh - no, a table alias is optional (unless you want to join to it).

Comment: the code above will work, i tried it before on a table. in oracle you could use inline views (with ... as select ...), but the sql above should work in general, not only for oracle.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a million!

Comment: Table alias is mandatory according to the ANSI/ISO SQL standard. However, some dbms's don't require it, but I never remember which ones. Apparently Oracle is one of them. Thanks for reminding me.